# Integrating factor/solve differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

I am asked to find the integrating factor and solve.

> $$ y\sin(y)dx + x(\sin(y) - y\cos(y))dy = 0.$$

I'm not sure on how to put this in the form of

$$y' + p(x)y = f(x)$$

to solve the equation. Or is there another method to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can separate dx and dy here:

$\frac {-(sin(y)−ycos(y))}{ysin(y)}dy=\frac {dx}{x}$

And solve the now separated variables equation, can you go on from here?

Comment: All that would be left is integrate both sides?

Comment: Yep, easy peasy. This is the most straightforward an ode can be.

Answer (score 1):

For an equation in the form
$$Mdx +Ndy=0$$
where $M$ and $N$ are functions of $x$ and $y$ the integrating factor is
$$\mu = e^{\displaystyle\int (M_y - N_x)/N dx}$$